# .htaccess and new site with /v2/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

i have one site `www.site.it`
and the new site `www.site.it/v2/`

is it possibile to redirect users from `www.site.it` to new site `www.site.it/v2/` BUT removing `/v2/` from url ?

I think i need a simple redirect from `www.site.it` to `www.site.it/v2/` but .htaccess on `www.site.it/v2/` must contain a rule to remove `/v2/` from url, showing the new site without `v2`. Is it possibile ?